# How to get superclass data member from subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I'm having trouble accessing a superclass data member from it's subclass.

So I have a superclass Store like this

```
public class Store {
    protected ArrayList<Audiobooks> ab;

    public Store(ArrayList<Audiobooks> ab)
    {
        this.ab = ab;
    }
    ...
}
```

ab is initialized and everything, then we have a subclass like this

```
public class Customer extends Store {

    ...
    public Customer(String id, String name, String address)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    }
    public void printAb(){
        for(int i = 0; i<ab.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(ab.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I end up getting a null pointer exception error. When the function is placed in the store class it works fine, but when its in the subclass Customer the null pointer exception occurs.

I tried to get it by using super.ab.... but no success.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: **Where** do you get the exception? What's the stack trace?

Comment: That's because, from the given code, `ab` is not instantiated (`new ArrayList<AudioBooks>()`).

Comment: Where is `ab` initialized in the superclass?

Comment: Where are the constructors for `Customer` and `Store`?

Comment: Also, a `Customer` is not a `Store`; you're misusing inheritance.

Comment: @SLaks could you elaborate on that, and could you provide an example of proper use of inheritance. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a

Comment: For example, a `Manager` is an `Employee`, or a `ComputerStore` is a `Store` (that would be better expressed using generics)

Comment: This doesn't even compile - Store has no default constructor, so you are obliged to call `super(somelist)`, which you aren't and which would solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Customer` constructor does not call you `Store` constructor, so the `ab` list is never instantiated.

To solve this, you either need to have your customer constructor call the store constructor:

```
public Customer(String id, String name, String address) {
    super(new ArrayList<Audiobooks>());
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}
```

Or have your customer constructor instantiate the list.  You also must have more than one constructor for the store class, otherwise the compiler would force you to call the constructor you are showing.  You may want to consider getting rid of the empty constructor that you apparently have on the store class if it does not put the class into a valid state.

Answer (score 1):

You access the `ab` property properly (otherwise you would have a compiler error).

Most likely you are not creating the object anywhere, try doing

```
 protected ArrayList<Audiobooks> ab = new ArrayList<Audiobooks>();
```

Also, it would be better if you use the most generic interface `List`

```
 protected List<Audiobooks> ab = new ArrayList<Audiobooks>();
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't state it clearly from my question prompt but, there is a test driver and the ab object is instantiated. If I just move the printAb function to the Store class and call it from the store object, it works fine. The issue is having that function in the customer class. If I move the printAB function into the customer class then I get a null pointer exception.

Comment: Maybe you are using a different constructor in the subclass (I assume the attribute is assigned an object there). What is the code for the constructors in `Store` and `Customer`?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

```
public class Customer extends Store {

    ...
    public Customer(ArrayList<Audiobooks> a,String id, String name, String address)
{
    super(a);
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    }
    public void printAb(){
        for(int i = 0; i<ab.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(ab.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

or do this

```
public class Customer extends Store {

        ...
        public Customer(String id, String name, String address)
    {
        a=new ArrayList<Audiobooks>(/*initial size*/);
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        }
        public void printAb(){
            for(int i = 0; i<ab.size(); i++){
                System.out.println(ab.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
    }
```